# Generating XPtr from Rcpp function

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am writing an `R` package in which one of the functions takes `Rcpp::XPtr` as an input (as a `SEXP`). However, the creation of `XPtr` from `Rcpp::Function` is something I want to do inside the package (i.e., the user should be able to input `Function`).

e.g, my package takes input generated as follows, which requires the user to write an additional function (here `putFunPtrInXPtr()`) and run the function in `R` to generate the `XPtr` (here `my_ptr`).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

typedef NumericVector (*funcPtr) (NumericVector y);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<funcPtr> putFunPtrInXPtr() {

  XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&timesTwo), false);
  return testptr;

}


/*** R
my_xptr <- putFunPtrInXPtr()
*/
```

How can I write something in which the user provides `Function user_fun` and I create the `XPtr`?

I tried

```
XPtr<funcPtr> package_fun(Function user_fun_input){

    XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&user_fun_input), false);
}
```

`user_fun_input` is the parameter name inside the package function, but I am getting the following error

```
cannot initialize a new value of type 'funcPtr' (aka 'Vector<14> (*) (Vector<14>') with an rvalue of type 'Rcpp::Function *' (aka 'Function_Impl<PreserveStorage> *')
```

Also, there is an `R` step involved in creating the pointer, I am not sure how to implement that in the package (my `.cpp` file).

I think the creation of `XPtr` from `Function` could be confusing to the user, so better to just take `Function` as input and create the pointer to it, inside the package. I do use the `XPtr` in my package to gain speed.

Suggestions are most appreciated!

Comment: Does this help: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/?

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at it, but in the cases mentioned in the link, the name of user defined function is already known and used. That will not be the case here.